# SASS syntax error: Undefined variable: "$em-base"

Tags: sass, mixins

I'm following a new [SASS structure guide here](http://thesassway.com/beginner/how-to-structure-a-sass-project?codekitCB=408479705.110592).

Trying to use the PX to EM mixin and seems like the variable isn't getting through.
But I have the **base** importing the **mixins** and the **typography** is imported last.

Main SASS file:

```
// Modules and Variables
@import "modules/base";

// Partials
@import "partials/normalize";
@import "partials/typography";
```

BASE.scss:

```
@import "colors";
@import "fonts";
@import "animation";
@import "mixins";
```

_mixins.scss:

```
/* PIXELS to EM */
// eg. for a relational value of 12px write em(12) when the parent is 16px
// if the parent is another value say 24px write em(12, 24)

// @include em(12);
@function em($pxval, $base: $em-base) {
    @if not unitless($pxval) {
        $pxval: strip-units($pxval);
    }
    @if not unitless($base) {
        $base: strip-units($base);
    }
    @return ($pxval / $base) * 1em;
}
```

And finally _typography.scss:

```
// widget table headers
section header h1 {
    font-family: LatoRegular;
    font-size: em(18);
}
```

**Error from CodeKit:**

```
Syntax error: Undefined variable: "$em-base".
    on line 6 of /assets/sass/partials/_typography.scss
    from line 38 of /assets/sass/dashboard.scss
```

Comment: Ohh nice article. Dale is an awesome guy! You might try putting your sass into http://sassmeister.com/ so you can see where you are going wrong...

Comment: surely you need to initialize your $em-base variable first like so: `$em-base: 16; // Default`. See https://gist.github.com/ngryman/5077672

Comment: AH fail! Lol I real em-base as em undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$em-base` is not defined in any of your files.

Comment: Dang it, forgot to set that variable, didn't see it at first `$em-base: 16;`